# Android AsyncTask only loaded one item into ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android

This only loads on of the titles in the url

It should load all of the items in this list

http://www.gamespy.com/index/release.html

```
  private class fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
                @Override 
                protected void onPreExecute(){
                     dialog = ProgressDialog.show(HtmlparserExampleActivity.this, "", 
                             "Loading. Please wait...", true);
                     dialog.show();

                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    //Setting the list of gameRelease Arrays

                     Document doc = null;
                            try {
                                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gamespy.com/index/release.html").get();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if(doc == null){

                            }
                            else{
                            // Get all td's that are a child of a row - each game has 4 of these
                                Elements games = doc.select("tr>  td.indexList1, tr > td.indexList2");


                                // Iterator over those elements     
                                ListIterator<Element> postIt = games.listIterator();   

                                //Loads all the items until there is no .hasNExt()
                                while (postIt.hasNext()) {     

                                    while (postIt.hasNext()) {     

                                        // Add the game text to the ArrayList     
                                        Element name = postIt.next();
                                         nameString = name.text();

                                        //Get the platform
                                        platform = postIt.next().text();

                                        //Get the URL 
                                        Element url = name.select("a").first();
                                         urlString = url.attr("href");

                                        //Get the Genre of the game
                                         genre = postIt.next().text();

                                        //Get the release date
                                         releaseDate = postIt.next().text();
                                        Log.v("Title", nameString);


                                        //Instantiating the GameReleaseAdapter





                            }

                }

            }
                            return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void notUsed){
                    dialog.dismiss();

                     ArrayList<GameRelease> gameList = new ArrayList<GameRelease>();
                      HtmlparserExampleActivity.this.setListAdapter(new GameReleaseAdapter(HtmlparserExampleActivity.this, gameList));
                        //Instantiating the GameReleaseAdapter


                        //Set the detals on the game releases to the setter and getter class GameRelease
                        gameList.add(new GameRelease(nameString, platform, genre, releaseDate, urlString));


                }
            }
```

}

When an item in the list is clicked i get this exception

```
08-16 22:15:52.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 22:15:52.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30528): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
08-16 22:15:52.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30528):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
08-16 22:15:52.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30528):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
08-16 22:15:52.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30528):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:298)
08-16 22:15:52.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30528):     at com.fttech.htmlParser.HtmlparserExampleActivity$1.onItemClick(HtmlparserExampleActivity.java:68)
08-16 22:15:52.736: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30528):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
```

EDIT: Adapter Code

```
    private class GameReleaseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GameRelease> {

                //Setting the GameRelease to a single item
                private ArrayList<GameRelease> items;

                //Make the layout for the items
                public GameReleaseAdapter(Context context,  ArrayList<GameRelease> items) {
                    // TODO: make a layout for each item which you'd call (for example) itemLayout
                    super(context, R.layout.item, items);
                    this.items = items;
                }

                //Inflate the layout to override getView.
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO: return an item view styled however you want or as shown in the tutorial
                    View v = convertView;
                    if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

                }
                    //Setting the texts to there rightful TextViews.
                    GameRelease o = items.get(position);
                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
                    TextView bt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);
                    TextView plat = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.platform);
                    TextView genre = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.genre);

                    tt.setText(o.getName());
                    bt.setText("RELEASE DATE: " +o.getReleaseDate());
                    plat.setText("PLATFORM: " + o.getPlatform());
                    genre.setText("GENRE: " + o.getGenre());

                    //Returning the View v which inflates the layout row.xml each time a item is added.
                    return v;


                }
```

EDIT: I now get this erro IndexOutOfBounds..

```
08-17 00:41:10.340: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 00:41:10.340: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14481): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 39, size is 1
08-17 00:41:10.340: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14481):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
08-17 00:41:10.340: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14481):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
08-17 00:41:10.340: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14481):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:341)
08-17 00:41:10.340: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14481):     at com.fttech.htmlParser.HtmlparserExampleActivity$1.onItemClick(HtmlparserExampleActivity.java:82)
08-17 00:41:10.340: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14481):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)
```

EDIT: Here is my onItemCLick method

```
this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //The debug is pointing me to this line
GameRelease  selectedGameRelease = myGameReleaseAdapter .getItem(position);
                    String urlString = selectedGameRelease.getUrl();

                    //Make what you like with the url
                    Toast.makeText(HtmlparserExampleActivity.this, urlString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent i = new Intent(HtmlparserExampleActivity.this, releaseInfo.class);
                    i.putExtra("url", urlString);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
                }
```

Comment: The log said that the arraylist parsed into your ArrayAdapter is empty? Can u post you Adapter code, maybe I can help you

Comment: Check my edit. Posted it

Comment: so you parse an `ArrayList<GameRelease>` into the `ArrayAdapter`, maybe you should check the size of `ArrayList` somewhere to make sure that it's not empty. If it is empty, does the `listView` show any row? I see that you also add an item into the `ArrayList` before `setAdapter()` is called, is this for debugging purpose?

Comment: in the onPostExecute? I didnt think it would matter since it would be done together

Comment: I wonder `ListView` is displaying any row. First, you should check that your Html Parser gives results (more than 0) then the size of the `ArrayList` which is parsed into the constructor of `ArrayAdapter`. If everything is 0, `ListView` shouldn't display any row

Comment: From experience do you think the parsing should be in a AsyncTask? Its really confusing and fustrating It works perfectly without it..just wanted to let the user know something is going on while they load..its a bit of a pause while it loads.

Comment: If it takes time and you don't want it to block the UI thread (user can still move around the screen) then you should put perform it in `Asynctask`. I think `AsyncTask` is working just fine here. Or you can use `Thread` with `Handler` to post result to UI.

Comment: hmmm.. Its just returning the last item on the list in the url its connecting to, idk why though

Comment: you are adding item into `ArrayList` inside `doInBackground()` right? Your `ArrayList` should be set as global in `AsyncTask` class and constructed in `onPreExecute()`, added new item in each loop of `doInBackground()` then parsed to `ArrayAdapter` in `onPostExecute`. I think that's the logic. You should review the flow of your code, I'm afraid that you are parsing a newly created `ArrayList` into the `ArrayAdapter` or there is something wrong with the part where new item is added into the `ArrayList`

Comment: I believe you are right, Its loading a new item into the arrayadapter each time, thats why the last item is the only one displayed. Could you post an answer of how you are saying it should look, and ill give you credit for answering this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Fetcher extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
   private ArrayList<GameRelease> list;

   protected void onPreExecute(){
       list = new ArrayList<GameRelease>();
       dialog.show();
   }

   protected void doInBackground(Void... args){
       // html parsing here
       while(postIt.hasNext()){
           // create a new GameRelease object for each entry you get from parsing
           list.add(new GameRelease(nameString, platform, genre, releaseDate, urlString));
       }
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(Void notUsed){
       dialog.dismiss;
       GameReleaseAdapter mAdapter = new GameReleaseAdapter(HtmlparserExampleActivity.this, list);
       setListAdapter(mAdapter);
   }
}
```

That's the logic I think is correct. Or you can the `setListAdapter()` with an empty `ArrayList` in `onCreate()`. Then you don't have to create the `ArrayList` inside `AsyncTask` but adding items to it then `onPostExecute()` you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. But first I suggest you try with this flow

Comment: Hey It worked! I guess i just had some confusion with the code

Comment: Got an error though when the item is clicked. with my onItemClickListener IndexOutOfBounds.Check my edit above.

Comment: Can you try changing `GameRelease o = items.get(position)
` in `getView()` with `this.getItem(position)` which returns the object referring to the item at that row. Of course items.get(position) should work normally but maybe you messed the `ArrayList` afterthat. If this doesn't work, try overriding other methods of `Adapter` like `getCount()`, `getItem()` and `getItemId()` or change to `BaseAdapter`

Comment: Try changing that line to `GameRelease selectedGameRelease = (GameRelease) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)`. I don't know whether you have to override `getItem` method in ArrayAdapter or not but you should still try

Comment: That did it. AsyncTask changed my whole flow lol. Thanks for all the help. I still have some issues but they rely with jsoup. Everything with my a sync task is good. Do you have any type of I.m? GTalk or anything?

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was odd for you to have two nested while() loops doing exactly the same thing...seems like it might be overkill. Did you mean for the inner while loop to be looping through an inner element of the document instead of repeating over the same items a second time?